# React refresh token interceptor

Tags: reactjs, authentication, axios, interceptor, auth-token

I have a problem with refreshing a token. After I updated the token, a request should be made with my configurations, but this does not happen. The token is updated, but the second time the getIserInfo method is executed, it does not work.

My axios interceptors:

```
import axios from "axios";
import {getToken, logOut, refreshToken, setUser} from "@/services/auth.service";

const HTTP = axios.create({baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT});

HTTP.interceptors.request.use(
    config => {
        const token = getToken();

        if (token) {
            config.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
        }

        return config;
    },
    error => Promise.reject(error)
)

HTTP.interceptors.response.use(
    response => response,
    async error => {
        debugger;
        const originalRequest = error.config;

        if (error.response.status === 401 && !originalRequest._retry) {
            originalRequest._retry = true;

            try {
                const response = await refreshToken();
                const {data} = await response;

                setUser(data);
            } catch (e) {
                logOut();
            }

            return HTTP(originalRequest);
        }

        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
)

export default HTTP
```

After executing the token, the getUserInfo method should have worked again

[image]

Works after removing headers

```
delete originalRequest["headers"]

return HTTP(originalRequest);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in axios 1.0+. After removing and switching to version 0.27, everything worked. It's most likely a bug on their part.